# using filter function to produce a list outputting non-common elements of two lists

Tags: list, haskell, recursion, functional-programming

So i am in need of a function which takes two lists, x and y and output a list of elements that are in List x BUT NOT IN List y.
ie. the output should look something like is

*Main> filterVars ["a","c","h","d"] ["c","b","a"]

```
      ["h","d"]
```

I want to use the filter function in Haskell to practice. My code is below;

```
    filterVars :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
    filterVars = filter IsInList (y:ys)
     where
IsiIList (x:xs) (y:ys) :: [a] -> [a] -> Bool
IsInList [] _ = []
IsiInList(x:xs) (y:ys)
                        | elem (x (y:ys)) = IsiInList (xs (y:ys))
                        | otherwise = x : IsiInList (xs (y:ys))
```

however I get the following error;

```
   Invalid type signature: IsInList (x : xs) (y : ys) :: ...
Should be of form <variable> :: <type>
     | IsInList (x:xs) (y:ys) :: [a] -> [a] -> Bool
```

My logic is as follows:

> When the function filterVars is called with arguments (x:xs) (y:ys), it checks to see the filter criteria IsInList.

> The function providing the filtering criteria, IsInList, takes both the arguments (x:xs) and (y:ys). if the first element of the list (x:xs) is an elements of (y:ys), then discard and move to the next element in the x list.

> For the case that an element of (x:xs) IS NOT IN list (y:ys), store this value and move onto the next element of the list x until list x is completely parsed through.

> return the list containing elements of list x that are not in list y

My confusion arises from my lack of experience with Haskell. Firstly the function filterVars must require two lists and output a list. However when i am defining the function, I use the filter function and the list y as arguments. I know filter outputs a list so i just wanted to know if my initial setup is correct (also would like to gain an insight to the flow of execution in Haskell)

Secondly I am not sure as to what the error means and how to resolve it. Does my logic make sense? Can this be done using lists or am i way of mark?

Comment: What do you want to happen if an element occurs multiple times in the first list?

Comment: [Data.List.Ordered.minus](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-ordlist-0.4.7.0/docs/Data-List-Ordered.html#v:minus) does just that (but only after you'd `sort` both its argument lists). You can consult its source code. `filter` is not a good choice as it forces you to use ``(`elem` y)`` which leads to quadratic code, but `minus` is linear, after the linearithmic `sort` stage.

Comment: Note that a function for unsorted lists also already exists in `Data.List` as the operator `\\` (but see the documentation regarding handling of duplicates).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has a few syntactic and semantic errors. I’ll explain the syntax issues and then get into the semantics of your solution.

- In Haskell, the names of functions, variables, and type variables must begin with a *lowercase* letter; capitalised names refer to types, data constructors, or modules. Therefore you need to rename `IsInList` to `isInList`, and fix the name typos.
- A `where` clause on a definition is followed by a block of variable bindings (`pattern = expression`). A block may be delimited by curly braces with items separated by semicolons (`{` … `;` … `;` … `}`) but it’s more common to use indentation-based *layout*. Therefore you need to indent the contents of the `where` block. A simple rule is to put a newline + indent (with spaces) after *any* layout keyword—`where`, `do`, `of`, or `let`—whenever you have a multi-line block.
- The type signature of a function is written as `name :: type`, but you’ve written what looks like a *pattern* on the left-hand side in `isInList (x:xs) (y:ys) :: [a] -> [a] -> Bool`. If you want to include a type signature here, you should write `isInList :: [a] -> [a] -> Bool`. However, I’m going to just remove the signature, for reasons I’ll explain below.

With those fixes, your code looks like this:

```
filterVars :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]
filterVars = filter isInList (y:ys)
  where
    isInList [] _ = []
    isInList (x:xs) (y:ys)
      | elem (x (y:ys)) = isInList (xs (y:ys))
      | otherwise = x : isInList (xs (y:ys))
```

Here’s my reading of this code:

- `filterVars` is equal to calling `filter` with two arguments, `isInList` and `y : ys`. `y` and `ys` are not in scope here, since you haven’t added them as parameters or pattern variables in the definition of `filterVars`.
- `isInList` takes two arguments; if the first is an empty list, it returns an empty list. This is not quite right, since `filter` has the type `(a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`, that is, its first argument should be a function which tests an element of the filtered list and returns a `Bool` to indicate whether it should be included in the result.
- If `isInList` is given two non-empty lists, then this is followed by a guard to decide which case to proceed to. You’re trying to use the `elem` function to test whether `x` is in the list `y : ys` as the condition here, but the way you call it, you’re passing `y : ys` as an argument to `x`, as if it were a function, and then calling `elem` on the result of that. If you want to pass two arguments to a function, you just separate them with spaces, and include parentheses if necessary for grouping, e.g.: `elem x (y : ys)`. You have the same issue with both calls to `isInList (xs (y:ys))`, when you probably intended `isInList xs (y:ys)`.

At this point it’s clear to me that you’re mixing up two things: filtering a list using `filter`, and filtering it by writing a recursive function.

If you want to write this using `filter`, you should begin with the problem statement: “a function which takes two lists, x and y and output[s] a list of elements that are in List x BUT NOT IN List y”. You want to write a function that takes two parameters, `x` and `y`, and filters `x` by a function that, given an element of `x`, returns true if the element is not in `y`.

This can be transcribed fairly literally:

```
filterVars :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]

-- Select the elements of ‘x’ not in ‘y’…
filterVars x y = filter notInY x
  where

    -- …where an element ‘e’ is not in ‘y’ if
    -- it’s ‘not’ the case that ‘e’ is an ‘elem’ of ‘y’.
    notInY e = not (elem e y)
```

But this has one issue: this function says it can take a list of values of *any* type `a`, and test for their presence in a list using `elem`, but this isn’t true: we could supply a type like `Double -> String` that’s not comparable at all! In reality, `elem` is restricted to types that are in the set of types with equality, the `Eq` typeclass, so we have to add an `Eq` constraint to the signature to enable the use of `elem`:

```
filterVars :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
```

Now, about the local type signature in the `where` block, the rule in Haskell is that if you write a polymorphic type signature with type variables (typically single letters like `a`, `b`, `f`, `m`…) then those variables are *local* to that type signature. So if you write this:

```
filterVars :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
filterVars x y = filter notInY x
  where
    notInY :: a -> Bool
    notInY e = not (elem e y)
```

That’s equivalent to this:

```
filterVars :: (Eq a1) => [a1] -> [a1] -> [a1]
filterVars x y = filter notInY x
  where
    notInY :: a2 -> Bool
    notInY e = not (elem e y)
```

The `a` of the `notInY` signature is *different* from the `a` in the `filterVars` signature, so this would cause a type error. The solution is to remove the local type signature or use the `ScopedTypeVariables` extension to explicitly define the scope of `a`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

filterVars :: forall a. (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
filterVars x y = filter notInY x
  where
    notInY :: a -> Bool
    notInY e = not (elem e y)
```

The `forall` introduces an explicit scope for `a`, so any `a` in a type signature in this definition refers to the *same* `a`. (An explicit `forall` is just like the `<T>` syntax in many imperative programming languages to define generic parameters.)

As a matter of style, you can also write this same structure in a few different ways, and you should make sure you understand these:

```
filterVars x y = filter (notIn y) x
  where
    notIn list e = not (elem e list)

filterVars x y = filter (\ e -> not (elem e y)) x

filterVars x y = filter (`notElem` y) x
```

This is very typical Haskell code, and a good concise solution. But since you’re learning Haskell, you should try to solve this problem with explicit recursion, effectively inlining the definition of `filter` into your code. For that, you *do* want to proceed by pattern-matching as you were trying to do in your `isInList` function. You can start with either of the following structures, using a `case` expression or multiple function equations, whichever you prefer:

```
filterVars :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
filterVars x y = case x of

  [] -> {- 1 -}

  e : rest
    | {- 2 -} -> {- 3 -}
    | otherwise -> {- 4 -}

filterVars :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
filterVars [] y = {- 1 -}
filterVars (e : rest) y
  | {- 2 -} = {- 3 -}
  | otherwise = {- 4 -}
```

And fill in the following details, marked with `{- … -}` comments in the code above:

1. `[a]`; What do you return when `x` is empty, i.e., what happens when you call `filterVars [] ["c", "b", "a"]` directly or as the base case of your recursion?
2. `Bool`; When `x` is non-empty, containing some element `e` and some (possibly empty) remainder `rest`, what condition do you use to test whether `e` is an element of `y`? (E.g. in `filterVars ["a", "d", "b"] ["c", "b", "a"]`, `e` is `"a"` and `rest` is `["d", "b"]`.)
3. `[a]`; What do you return when `e` *is* an element of `y`? Should you keep or discard the element? What do you do with the `rest` of the input?
4. `[a]`; What do you return when `e` is *not* in `y`? What do you do with the `rest` of the input then?

Recall that you can always step through Haskell code using *equational reasoning*, by substituting things on either side of an `=` sign, since `=` actually means equal! For example, if your function had a case `f [] = []`, then whenever you see `f []`, you can *replace* it with `[]`; if it had a case `f (x : xs) = x + f xs`, when you see a call to `f [1, 2, 3]`, this is the same as `f (1 : [2, 3])`, and likewise `f (1 : (2 : (3 : [])))`, so you can match `x` = `1` and `xs` = `2 : (3 : [])` and substitute their values in the right-hand side `x + f xs` → `1 + f [2, 3]`.

Comment: Ok that makes a lot more sense. The only thing I don't quite understand is how Haskell knows that the element 'e' is from the list x? Furthermore where is the recursion occurring? I can't seem to understand how the it goes through list x, element by element, comparing each to the entire list of y. The signature of the elem function compares a single variable with a list however we supply two list in the form of e, y.

Comment: @Zain: *You* know `e` is from `x` because you’re matching on `x` to *define* `e`. A match like `case x of { [] -> (A); e : rest -> (B) }` is similar to `if null x then (A) else let { e = head x; rest = tail x } in (B)`. I haven’t written it out for you, but the recursive calls would be in cases 3 & 4 in my example, like what you already wrote in your `isInList`. You’re mistaken about the type of `e`: if `x` has type `[a]` for some type `a`, then `e` is *not* of type `[a]`, it’s just `a`. (This may *happen* to be a list type, like the `String` in your example, but that’s not relevant here.)